# For any coprime integers $(x, y)$, $m\geq 2$, $\delta\geq 1$, is it true that $\mid x^m - y^{m+\delta} \mid \geq \delta$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is it true that if $x,y,m,\delta$ are integers, $\gcd(x,y)=1$, $m\ge2$, $\delta\ge1$, then $$|x^m-y^{m+\delta}|\ge\delta?$$

Any proofs or references will be most welcome.

Comment: Can you specify x,y, m and  $ \delta $ ? In which set are they? Natural numbers, real numbers etc. ? Is there some relation between them?

Comment: $|8^2-4^{2+1}|<1$.

Comment: Sorry had forgotten the condition that $(x,y)$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @Isaac. Please consider that it might be a bit rude to radically change the question after it's already been answered.

Comment: @User, noted with thanks, and any inconveniences caused are sincerely regretted.

Comment: Isaac, the thing to do is to get some easy computer language, people seem to like Python for example. Then you can run your own simulations before asking any questions. https://www.python.org/ I use C++ , I also have Sage and gp-Pari, all of which were free.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you think of this particular statement? Is there any particular reason you thought it might hold?

Comment: You might be interested in looking up the abc conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

$|5^3-2^{3+4}|<4{}{}{}{}{}$.